# Inverse a complete Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to inverse a complete sheet, which means, the first row becomes the last row, the last row becomes the first row, etc. (without changing the columns).

The only way I think of, is running on the rows from bottom to top, and copy each row to a new sheet.

Comment: Add a temp column with the row number in it, then do a descending sort on it and copy the results.

Comment: Good idea, thanks :)

Comment: I have a template somewhere where I stuck excel sheet into variant array, used a sorting logic to reverse it. Putting it back onto the sheet is easy, but if you want ill dig up that piece of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you already have an answer; but I always try to keep vba as simple as possible.
Just change `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` as required to meet your needs.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow
        ws.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Cut
        ws.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got bored and decided to just write it up real quick.

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim pickUp As Variant
    Dim newArr() As String
    Dim rowC As Long, colC As Long, i As Long, j As Long, z As Long

    rowC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    z = rowC
    colC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ReDim newArr(1 To rowC, 1 To colC)
    pickUp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

    For i = LBound(pickUp, 1) To UBound(pickUp, 1)
        For j = LBound(pickUp, 2) To UBound(pickUp, 2)
            newArr(rowC, j) = pickUp(i, j)
        Next j
        rowC = rowC - 1
    Next i

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    With ws
        ws.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(z, colC)).Value2 = newArr
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Boredom must be contagious.

```
Sub FlipTheScript()
    Dim data As Variant, result As Variant

    data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value
    ReDim result(1 To UBound(data), 1 To UBound(data, 2))

    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    For r = 1 To UBound(data)
        For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            result(UBound(data) - r + 1, c) = data(r, c)
        Next
    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value = result
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a dummy column
2. Fill by number
3. Sort in descending order
4. Delete the numbered column

   ```
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim i As Long

   Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

   Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
   For i = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       ws.Cells(i, 1) = i
   Next i

   With ws.Sort
       .SortFields.Clear
       .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlDescending
       .SetRange ws.UsedRange
       .Apply
   End With

   Columns("A:A").Delete
   ```